# Is the use of "avec" optional when saying "with her dead"?

Tags: grammaire

> (**Avec**) Sherry morte, la princesse n'a plus aucune rivale dans le palais.

In English, you use the structure "with + noun + adjective" to say, for instance, "with a window open", "with the TV on", or "with all this noise going on".

When you want to say "with Sherry dead", can you omit "avec {with}" from the top of the phrase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say you can't use the form "avec + noun + adjective". So the possibilites are:

> Sherry morte, [...]
>
> Avec la mort de Sherry, [...]
>
> Sherry étant morte, [...]

So to me you MUST omit "avec".

Comment: So in French, it takes the form of "Sherry **being** dead" rather than "**WIth** Sherry dead". And if you want to use "**avec**", you need to couple it with a **noun**, correct? Merci.

Comment: @LUNA It's correct in this case but I can't say if it's a rule. I was hoping someone to precise my answer with an official rule.